# I'm unable to use rpmbuild to build nagios-3.5.0 RPM @RHEL6

Tags: redhat, nagios, rhel6, rpm

I'm unable to build RPM w/ nagios 3.5.0 (last one that worked for me was 3.2.3):

```
# md5sum nagios-3.5.0.tar.gz 
aeef195d2033cc362bf6cb972bcc8f07  nagios-3.5.0.tar.gz
# rpmbuild -tb nagios-3.5.0.tar.gz 
warning: line 40: prereq is deprecated: PreReq: /usr/bin/logger, chkconfig, sh-utils, shadow-utils, sed, initscripts, fileutils, mktemp
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VOVWNc
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf nagios-3.5.0
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /root/nagios-3.5.0.tar.gz
+ /bin/tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd nagios-3.5.0
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VOVWNc: line 38: cd: nagios-3.5.0: No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VOVWNc (%prep)


RPM build errors:
    line 40: prereq is deprecated: PreReq: /usr/bin/logger, chkconfig, sh-utils, shadow-utils, sed, initscripts, fileutils, mktemp
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VOVWNc (%prep)
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
# uname -a
Linux XXX.XXX.XXX 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 14 15:48:21 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -q rpm-build
rpm-build-4.8.0-32.el6.x86_64
#
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Yes: Use a repo that packages this stuff, like EPEL.

Comment: @SvW while your comment doesn't really answer my question at all, I do appreciate your suggestion, yet I still would like to know what's wrong in my scenario. and for all `downvoters`: _PLEASE_ explain why are you downvoting (w/out your comments I can't improve myself).

Comment: I suspect that people are downvoting your question because you're getting some pretty obvious error messages.  It's entirely possible that the spec file in the nagios tarball is simply unmaintained.  It's apparent from the errors that the spec file no longer corresponds to how Nagios is packaged.

Comment: @larsks right and I'm here to find a solution, as I couldn't figure it out by myself, I'm sure someone else ran into same situation here and there and I'm hoping they'll share their valuable experience w/ rest of open source community).

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you because there is merit to building your own RPM. Usually, when a particular version isn't readily available. However, [in this case it is](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/nagios-3.5.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm). It's just not possible to justify the headache. It's hard to guess how the EPEL guys got it to work, but if you want to learn, I would suggest extracting their RPM to see.

Comment: Not to mention, if you aren't using EPEL you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @AaronCopley Thank you for your comment, there could be number of reasons why would one want to use own RPM and not from a 3rd party (such as epel).

Comment: @MichaelHampton there are more then one way to do things, building own RPMs vs using EPEL is not necessarily wrong, it's just another way of doing things. I do agree in most of the cases using EPEL is a lot easier and more convenient, yet that's not the _ONLY_ way).

Comment: alexus: There aren't really many *good* reasons for using your own RPM.  You can always download the *source* RPM from EPEL and modify it as necessary to support the version of nagios you want with the configuration you want.  The folks behind EPEL (and other large package sources) have a lot of experience building high-quality packages and usually provide better starting point then doing it on your own from scratch.

Comment: @larsks I absolutely have _NO_ doubt whatsoever about folks behind EPEL, there is no question in my mind that community of people would be a lot more knowledgeable then one person) yet again we're offtrack, as I'm not here to discuss EPEL community, but rather then see if I can get solution)

Comment: Your solution is to grab the EPEL source rpm and modify it to fit your needs.  The spec file included in the nagios tarball is obviously unmaintained and no longer compatible with either your OS release or the Nagios package itself.  You could of course also write a spec file from scratch, and that's a valuable skill to learn but not particularly relevant to this question.

Comment: @larsks company's policy is prohibits using 3rd party RPMs (such as EPEL), while this may be a solution for majority of folks out there, this is _NOT_ a solution for me.

Comment: Why didn't you say so in the first time? Then I suggest you grab the EPEL nagios.spec file, rename it to my-nagios.spec, give it a try and see what may go wrong. This is what I do normally. I did this for Nagios a very long time ago corrected a few bugs and then resubmitted it to the Nagios project to help with maintaining its own RPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nagios (rpmbuild) Enterprise Linux | alexus' blog](http://alexus.org/howto/nagios-rpmbuild-enterprise-linux)

```
tar -zxf nagios-3.5.0.tar.gz
rm nagios-3.5.0.tar.gz
mv nagios nagios-3.5.0
sed -i 's/datarootdir/datadir/' nagios-3.5.0/nagios.spec
tar -czf nagios-3.5.0.tar.gz nagios-3.5.0
rpmbuild -tb nagios-3.5.0.tar.gz
ls rpmbuild/RPMS/*/nagios-3.5.0*rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said above the issue is that spec file is no more maintained

```
# zcat nagios-3.5.0.tar.gz | tar -tf - | head -3
nagios/
nagios/OutputTrap.pm
nagios/p1.pl
```

As you can see, the folder name is nagios, but in the spec file it's try to change dir to the nagios-3.5.0

```
+ cd nagios-3.5.0
```

If you can't use 3rd party repo such as EPEL, I will suggest to take spec file from http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS/nagios-3.5.0-1.el6.src.rpm and build your own package